# Is the measurement of the big O notation correct in my algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

[Here is the link to algorithm without comments, to see better](https://github.com/EduardoSebastian/Euler/blob/master/7.js)

```js
function getLastFactor(n) {
 var tempArr = [2, 3], max = Math.sqrt(n); /* (1 + 1) 
 it is despised
 */
 for(var i = 5; i < max; i += 2) { /* 
 (sqrt(n) - 5)  ---> ( 5 is despised )
 */
  if(n%i) continue; /* 
  sqrt(n) - 5 operations 
  PD: Should I add this? or is it already included in the for, in (sqrt(n) - 5 above) ?
 */
  if(check(tempArr, i)) continue; // How do I measure this? If I do not have security of the number?
  tempArr.push(i); // 1 operation it is despised
 }
 return tempArr[tempArr.length - 1]; // 1 operation
}

function check(array, i) {
 for(var j = 0, l = array.length; j < l; ++j) { // sqrt(n) operations 
  var cur = array[j]; // 1 operation
  if(!(i%cur)) return true; // 1 operation
 }
 
// O(3 * sqrt(n))
```

I do not know what really add up, I have read that that is not important, since the `Big O` notation standardizes that, eliminating the terms of minor order. But I have many doubts, like some that I left in the code itself and also:

- 1) Should I count operations that **depend** on a conditional? , Imagine I have a condition, if you evaluate true, a cycle will be done to increase the efficiency in n operations, this should be taken into account since it makes a big change.
- 2) I think the efficiency of this code is `O (sqrt (n) * 3)`, is this correct?

This problem is not a duplicate of another, I have read a lot by the network and especially in this community, and almost all the questions / answers are based on the theoretical and almost never have seen theoretical and practical examples at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when using big-o notation drop all constants, so `O (sqrt (n) * 3)` is actually `O (sqrt (n))`.

To correctly analyze the asymptotic complexity of this code we need some background in number theory. What this algorithm basically performs is determining the prime factors of `n` (only the greatest is returned). Main part of program is a `for` loop that iterates over all odd numbers from `5` to `sqrt(n)`, so the number of iterations is `(sqrt(n) - 5) / 2`, or in big-o terminology, `O(sqrt(n))`.

Next, there is a statement `if(n%i) continue;` that eliminates all numbers that are not divisors of `n` (regardless whether they are prime or not). So, the rest of code is executed only when `i` is a divisor of `n`. [Asymptotic bound for number of divisors](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/) is `O(n^{1 / ln(ln(n))})`.

Finally, there is a function `check` that iterates over the array `tempArr` which contains prime divisors of `n` found so far. How many prime divisors does a positive integer `n` have? [Asymptotic bound for number of prime divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217411/number-of-distinct-prime-divisors-of-an-integer-n-is-o-log-n-log-log-n) is in a worst case (when `n` is so called a [primorial number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)) `O(ln(n) / ln(ln(n)))`.

Let's now sum up everything. Even if we assume that `n` is primorial and that all prime divisors are found quickly (so `array.length` has a maximum possible value), the asymptotic complexity of the part of code after `if(n%i) continue;` is `O(n^{1 / ln(ln(n))} * ln(n) / ln(ln(n)))`. It is not that easy to see, but this grows slower than `O(sqrt(n))`, so the total complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: (sqrt(n) - 5) / 2 , why divide by 2 ?

Comment: @J.Uchu Because of `i += 2`. You are checking only odd numbers between 5 and `sqrt(n)`, i.e. one half of them.

Comment: Is so much maths for my actual knowledge, to learn number theory, what should I know? Calculus? matrices? PS: I'm still at school

Comment: @J.Uchu Asymptotic bounds for number of (prime) divisors are high level math, there are many scientific papers that cover that area. If you are still in school, don't bother too much with it. Start by studying big-o of simpler algorithms, there are many examples on the Internet. Number theory is a separate area of math, if you wish to go deeper into that, start by studying Diophantine equations, congruences, Fermat theorem etc.